# Equal height of flexbox items

Tags: html, css

I cannot make flexbox items same height, while in one of the item is more content. Therefore border on the right is not equal height than others.

I would like to achive border in all items equal (as red line on the below image).

How can I do that?

[image]

```css
.contacts-list {
  color: #333;
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}

.contacts-list li {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #333;
  align-items: center;
}

.contacts-list__contact {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.contacts-list__address span {
display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="contacts">
    <ul class="contacts-list">
      <li class="contacts-list__contact">Contact</li>
      <li class="contacts-list__address">
        <span>Company Name</span>
        <span>Address</span>
        <span>City</span>
     </li>
      <li class="contacts-list__phone">+ 1 123 456 78</li>
      <li class="contacts-list__email">some@funnyemail.com</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to remove margin from `li` which is creating space from top and bottom. second if you want to align center items then you have to give `display:flex` to `li`. Hope this will help you

```css
.contacts-list {
  color: #333;
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}

.contacts-list li {
  flex: 1;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #333;
  align-items: center;

}

.contacts-list__contact {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.contacts-list__address span {
display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="contacts">
    <ul class="contacts-list">
      <li class="contacts-list__contact">Contact</li>
      <li class="contacts-list__address">
        <span>Company Name</span>
        <span>Address</span>
        <span>City</span>
     </li>
      <li class="contacts-list__phone">+ 1 123 456 78</li>
      <li class="contacts-list__email">some@funnyemail.com</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```